# why do we need the didUpdateWidget and build method in a statefull widget?

Tags: flutter

why do we need the didUpdateWidget method in a state?
Build is called anyway, cant we add the logic there too?
The only difference is, that we dont have a reference to the old widget as paramter or do i miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can implement logic in the build method when something is reloaded on your screen.
`didUpdateWidget` is called every time when the corresponding widget is recreated

But, the difference is that, when we can compare some values and based on those values we can take decisions on the app.

**Example:**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  int getInitialValue() {
    return 1;
  }
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _currentValue = 10;
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(MyApp oldWidget) {
      if(oldWidget.getInitialValue() != _currentValue) {
        // Perform animation
        // Fetch data from server
      }
  }
 }
```

Above is just an example of how we can use `didUpdateWidget()`, we can do similar stuff for many other scenarios

Comment: Ok, now i understand what i can use it for. when the widget changes, cause of the parent widget for example, didUpdateWidget and build is called. if i call the setState method of the state, only build is called. build can be called many times, it makes no sense to subscribe to stream or create animations inside the build method. thank you :)